# "Smart" vapor barriers

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

.Hi, all!

I've been working through insulating my kitchen. Had a drywall guy out who'll be patching all my stuff. He suggested that in his exp poly vapor barrier tended to create moisture problems. I wasn't sure, but figured I'd dig in. Looks like there might be truth to it, particularly if your newer structure has low permeability outer sheathing (mine does). There's a new family of products from different brands, referred to as "smart" (or I might call them "variable") vapor barriers though, that allegedly tackle this issue. One such product is Certainteed MemBrain. I've also found some info that perhaps the permeability of different products is suited better for different climates.

Does anyone have any experience with these? Are some better than others? Anything in particular you can recommend?

Cheers!